# Trying to develop a recursive type-level function to derive function input and output

Tags: haskell, typeclass, gadt, data-kinds

The following definitons are kind of required to understand what I'm asking:

```
data Param = PA | PB | PC

data R p a where
  A :: S a -> R PA (S a)
  B :: S a -> R PB (S a)

data S a where
  Prim :: a -> S a
  HO   :: R pa a -> R pb b -> S ((R pa a) -> (R pb b))
  Pair :: R pa a -> R pb b -> S ((R pa a), (R pb b))

data Box r a = Box r a
```

I would like to write a function using these definitions that works as follows:

```
trans :: t -> TransIn t -> TransOut t
```

where

```
TransIn (R 'PA (S a)) = a
TransIn (R 'PB (S a)) = a
TransIn (R 'PA (S (r1, r2))) = (TransIn r1, TransIn r2)
TransIn (R 'PA (S (r1, r2))) = (TransIn r1, TransIn r2)
TransIn (R 'PA (S (r1 -> r2))) = Error
TransIn (R 'PB (S (r1 -> r2))) = TransOut r1 -> TransIn r2
```

and

```
TransOut (R 'PA (S a)) = Box (R 'PA (S a)) a
TransOut (R 'PB (S a)) = Box (R 'PB (S a)) a
TransOut (R 'PA (S (r1, r2))) = (TransOut r1, TransOut r2)
TransOut (R 'PA (S ((R p (S a)), R p (S b))))) = (Box (R p (S a)) a, Box (R p (S b)) b)
TransOut (R 'PA (S (r1 -> r2))) = Error
TransOut (R 'PB (S (r1 -> r2))) = TransIn r1 -> TransOut r2
```

The basic idea is to accept different shapes of input and produce different shapes of output based on the constructor used for S and the parameter chosen when building R. I've been trying to do this using classes with data kinds, but I'm getting kind mis-match errors. I was wondering if there was an intuitive, clean way to encode this type of thing.

The current attempt I have is as follows:

```
class Transform t a where
  data TransIn t a:: *
  data TransOut t a:: *
  trans :: t -> TransIn t a -> TransOut t a

instance Transform (R Param (S a)) a where
  data TransIn (A (S a)) a :: a
  data TransOut (A (S a)) a :: Box (R Param (S a)) a
  trans t a = Box t a

instance Transform (R Param (S (a -> b))) a where
  data TransIn (A (S (a -> b))) (a -> b) :: TransIn a -> TransIn b
  data TransOut (A (S (a -> b))) (a -> b) :: TransOut a -> TransOut b
  trans _ _ = undefined
```

This approach complains that the first argument of R should have kind Param but Param has kind *, and I'm not sure how to correct this. When adding a constraint and using a variable, I got here:

```
instance (p :: Param) => Transform (R p (S a)) a where
  data TransIn (R p (S a))) a :: a
  data TransOut (R p (S a)) a :: Box (R p (S a)) a
  trans t a = Box t a
```

Of course, Haskell has refused to let me use a Kind as a constraint. I'm pretty lost, and I'm not sure where to go with this. Any help or guidance would be invaluable.

Comment: I think there's a typo: The second copy of the line `TransIn (R 'PA (S (r1, r2))) = (TransIn r1, TransIn r2)` should be `TransIn (R 'PB ...) = ...`. And the same for `TransOut`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with a single-parameter type class with two associated type families for `TransIn` and `TransOut`.

```
class Transform t where
  type TransIn t
  type TransOut t
  trans :: t -> TransIn t -> TransOut t
```

Now you need six instances for the six equations for `TypeIn` and `TypeOut`. Here is the first one.

```
instance Transform (R PA (S a)) where
  type TransIn (R PA (S a)) = a
  type TransOut (R PA (S a)) = Box (R PA (S a)) a
  trans t a = error "implement me!"
```

Note that the definitions for `TransIn` and `TransOut` are literally the equations from the question.